# onmouseover change image

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I was trying to put a link on an image. When the mouse is over the image, the image changes from login_button_22.jpg to login_button_11.jpg. I am using the following piece of code, which is working for IE but not for chrome and others. Any ideas how to modify it, to work for all explorers? Thanks

```
<a href="#top"

onmouseover="document.getElementById('myimage1').src='img/login_button_22.jpg';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('myimage1').src='img/login_button_11.jpg';" >

    <img src="img/login_button_11.jpg" id="myimage1" />

</a>
```

Comment: Your code works for me on Chrome, Firefox and Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/hkkvp/

Comment: I have a made a fiddle but it's working http://jsfiddle.net/jPavR/

Comment: still not working on my laptop and desktop pc using win7 and win8. any ideas why it may not working on me?

Comment: Are you sure JavaScript is enabled?

Comment: yes it is enabled. it was by default